# Find all named cells with a specific character in the name and a blank value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find each named cell where the name ends with _ and the value of the cell is blank. This is the code I'm using to no avail. (The msgbox is just to help me see how many it finds.) The _ is to make the cell required, if you know a better way (without having to do each one at a time) please let me know. Thanks!

```
namedrange = 0

For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Names
If Right(cell.Name, 1) = "_" And cell.Value = "" Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
namedrange = namedrange + 1
End If
Next cell

MsgBox namedrange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
requiredmissing = 0

Dim RangeName As Name
Dim namedrange As Long

For Each RangeName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Right(RangeName.Name, 1) <> "_" Then GoTo skipthisone

        If Range(RangeName.Name).Value = "" Then
        Range(RangeName.Name).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        requiredmissing = requiredmissing + 1
        Else
        Range(RangeName.Name).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If

    all = all + 1
skipthisone:
Next RangeName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim RangeName As Name
    Dim namedrange As Long
    namedrange = 0

    For Each RangeName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If Right(RangeName.Name, 1) = "_" And Range(RangeName).Value = "" Then
        Range(RangeName).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        namedrange = namedrange + 1
        End If
        all = all + 1
    Next RangeName

    MsgBox namedrange
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, @Mrig! The 'And Range'... needed a tweak and I wound up with the below. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JoePatrick - Technically `Range(RangeName).Value` and `Range(RangeName.Name).Value` both will give you same result because if `RangeName` is the cell address then `RangeName.Name` is nothing but the name given to the same cell address.

Comment: Hi, @Mrig, I'm not sure about the technicality but it got a runtime error 13 mismatch without the tweak. It was returning the value of the cell instead of the name of the cell.

Comment: @JoePatrick - Hi, not able to reproduce the error you are getting because for me the code is executing fine. Nonetheless if its working for you after making changes, well and good.